# Vuetify list items not showing properly

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify to show the list items properly like in the below structure

```
Interests

btn1 btn2
btn3 btn4

Not Interests

btn1 btn2
btn3 btn4
```

But the title "Interests", "Not Interests" failed to appear properly.

```
 <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 v-for="kid in kids">
          <v-card color="blue-grey darken-2" class="white--text">
            <v-card-title primary-title>
            <div>
              <div class="headline">{{kid.name}}</div>
              <span class="grey--text">{{kid.school.name}}</span>
            </div>
              <!--<div>Listen to your favorite artists and albums whenever and wherever, online and offline.</div>-->
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-list>
                <v-list-tile @click="">
                  <v-list-tile-content>
                    <v-list-tile-title>Interests</v-list-tile-title>
                    <div>
                    <v-btn flat dark v-for="(interest, idx) in kid.interests" :key="idx">{{interest}}</v-btn>
                    </div>
                  </v-list-tile-content>
                </v-list-tile>

                <v-divider></v-divider>

                <v-list-tile @click="">
                  <v-list-tile-content>
                    <v-list-tile-title>Not Interests</v-list-tile-title>
                    <div>
                    <v-btn flat dark v-for="(nointerest,idx) in kid.notinterests" :key="idx">{{nointerest}}</v-btn>
                    </div>
                  </v-list-tile-content>
                </v-list-tile>
              </v-list>
            </v-card-actions>

          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
```

I tried setting fixed height for the list items, but still I got the wrong alignment.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qYeaKB?editors=1010)

Comment: What's the reason for using `list` in this case? It seems to me that you should be using `chips` instead of `buttons` here. And you could provide more template examples wrt number of buttons displayed (e.g. desired template when there is 1 button, or 5 buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly way is using `two-line` option

```
 <v-list two-line>
  ...
 </v-list>
```

Demo https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/aGeJPe

You can set height for list tile if you want

```
.list__tile {
  height: 5rem !important;
}
```

Comment: This because of button text is too long. You can use `<v-btn small>` to use small button size, or you can use css to change to width of button. I've updated above codepen sample

Comment: thanks but the items list (it should be an item rather than a button) should be dynamic. If I add one more interest, then design should get collapsed.

Comment: If it can be multiple line, then you should use `v-list-group` (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists#example-expansion-lists) for it

Comment: I don't know which option to choose maybe list or something but I want the buttons to get appear like above. Note that num of buttons to get added should not go beyond 5.